# prove $P_{A^{-1}}(x)=\frac{x^{3}}{P_A(0)}P_A(\frac{1}{x}) $

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is invertible with $A\in Mat_3(\mathbb{C})$, prove for all $x\not = 0$ we have:

$P_{A^{-1}}(x)=\frac{x^{3}}{P_A(0)}P_A(\frac{1}{x}) $

**My work**

We know by Cayley-Hamilton theorem:

$P_{A}(x) = x^{3} - \mathrm{tr}(A)x^{2} + \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A))x - \det(A)$

Then,

$P_A(0)=-det(A)$

$P_A(1/x)=\frac{1}{x^3}-tr(A)\frac{1}{x^2}+tr(adj(A))\frac{1}{x}-det(A)$

Then,

$$\frac{x^3}{P_A(0)}P_A(\frac{1}{x})=(\frac{x^3}{-det(A)})(\frac{1}{x^3}-tr(A)\frac{1}{x^2}+tr(adj(A))\frac{1}{x}-det(A))=-\frac{1}{det(A)}+\frac{tr(A)x}{det(A)}-\frac{tr(adj(A)x^2}{det(A)}+x^3$$

Moreover,

$P_{A^{-1}}(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}-tr(A^{-1})\frac{1}{x^2}+tr(adj(A^{-1})\frac{1}{x}-det(A^{-1})$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can get this from looking at $P_{A^{-1}}(x) = \det(xI - A^{-1}) = \det [xA^{-1} (A - \frac{1}{x}I)]$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you mean $$P_{A^{-1}}(x)=x^3-tr(A^{-1})x^2+tr(adj(A^{-1}))x-det(A^{-1}).$$

You showed that $$\frac{x^3}{P_A(0)}P_A\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{det(A)}+\frac{tr(A)x}{det(A)}-\frac{tr(adj(A))x^2}{det(A)}+x^3.$$

To reach the desired conclusion, recall that:

- $\det{A}\times\det{A^{-1}}=1;$
- $A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det A}\text{adj}(A)$.

Comment: Thanksssss!!!! How can i prove this? $\frac{tr(A)x}{det(A)}=tr(adj(A^{-1})x$

Comment: @Bvss12 $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$ The trace is linear: $\tr (cB) = c \tr(B)$ so $\tr A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \tr(\operatorname{adj}(A))$. Now swap $A$ and $A^{-1}$ to get $\tr(A) = \frac{1}{\det A^{-1}} \tr(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}))$.

Comment: You're welcome :) You use the formula $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\text{adj}(A)$ and what Trevor Gunn said.